# Basic Auth working locally but not on Travis

Tags: basic-authentication, behat, travis-ci, goutte, guzzle

In order to use my API, I need to be authentified to do some actions. I'm using Behat + Mink for my tests.

I have two ways to authentificate : either by a token (sending a POST request with some parameters, then getting a token that I can user elsewhere), which is working fine on a local environment and on the Travis Environment, or i can use the Basic Auth.

On my local environment, the Basic Auth works perfectly fine, and I don't remember having configured anything special... But when i'm executing my tests on Travis, it seems that it does not take it into account.

As I said, i'm using Behat + Mink (+ Goutte, so I'm also using Guzzle), and after the request was sent to Curl, it seems that the header containing the Authorization (`Authorization: Basic (base64_txt)`) just... disappear. Even when i'm on a local environment. But still, it retains my login information. But not on the Travis environment, which should not really be any different than my local env...

[Here is the gist link.](https://gist.github.com/843e9f424656e0b114f6)

I don't know if there is enough information, but if you need more, please do not hesitate to tell me, I'll provide as much as I can.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please add a link to your repository and/or failing Travis build. It would make this quite a bit easier to debug.

Comment: These are private repos, so it is a bit difficult... But I could add the travis output for the build that failed ?

Comment: I know guzzle has a curl auth plugin. Are you using it? 
http://guzzlephp.org/guide/plugins.html#curl-auth-plugin

Comment: Like I said, it works perfectly on my local, as i'm using behat with goutte (and then guzzle). But when i'm trying it on travis, it fails. The thing is, the configuration between the two builds does not change at all... !